# Can you use <input> without a server?

Tags: html

I want to use ‹input› without PHP because my code editor (Glitch.com) doesn't work well with PHP. Is there a way to use ‹input› without server-side code? Example: Somehow stores the input as a variable. This is incorrect, I know but can I do something like this?

```
    <form>
      <label for="FirstName">First name:</label>
     var input =  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
   </form>
```

Then like use a getElementById and replace the text with the input variable.

I know I can use prompt(), but I don't want a window popping up, but something like this:

```html
<form>
  <label for="Username">Enter New Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you can help, 
Thanks!

Update:
What I am trying to accomplish is I am making a scorekeeper, and I want the user to be able to rename themselves. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, `<input>` has nothing to do with the server side inherently. You can get and set the value with JS to your heart's content, open alerts, send XHR requests, write data to local storage..... I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here though--maybe provide more context for your actual goal.

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definetely achieve this using Javascript:

```js
const firstName = document.querySelector('#fname');
const lastName = document.querySelector('#lname');
const submit_button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
const heading = document.querySelector('h1')

submit_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  heading.textContent = "Last Name: " + lastName.value;
})
```

```html
<h1 class="display-first-name"></h1>
<form>
  <label for="FirstName">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="LastName">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```